# siam bst editing

Tags: bibtex

I am currently trying to use the SIAM.bst or the siam bibliography style for my thesis, and I find myself requiring to make a few edits to the presentation of the references which I am unable to do. I would like to have the following format:

J. D. Doe. **This is a journal title.** *This it the journal, volume number, pages,* year.

And I would like to not have the volume number or pages show up with vol. or pp. respectively, and would also like to have the citations appear in order of appearance in the text.

I am also not opposed to using just regular \begin{thebibliogrpahy}, what I was really after was the font style that comes with the siam style, so if there is a way to just incorporate that in a tex file that would do well too!

I am reposting this question as I am now signed into my account and can respond to answers!

Comment: Is this query an almost perfectly exact duplicate of [siam.bst editing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/405009/5001)? Feel free to delete the earlier posting (or this one...).

Comment: Yeah mate it is, I couldn't reply to your comment on the other one because I didn't have enough reputation :o To answer your question, I have books also to reference but I would like the formatting to be done in the same way

Comment: Unless you need make only a couple of very minor changes, I always recommend against hacking an existing style file, which is a tedious and error-prone process, unless you happen to be a real expert in BibTeX's infix stack language. (Are you?) You're much better off running the `makebst` utility, which is part of the [custom-bib](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib?lang=en) package. You'll be asked a series of multiple-choice questions, and at the end of the process you'll have a bespoke bibliography style file with nearly bullet-proof, well-debugged code.

Comment: Oh I am definitely not an expert in that! I had looked at the makebst option but like most things with Latex I found it somewhat confusing, I wasn't sure what parts I needed to download etc. Would you be able to walk me through what I need to do?